# Get position of element in react-native FlatList

Tags: react-native

I have an horiziontal FlatList where inside there are some items.
Is possible to know the position (x, y, width and height) of clicked item?

I tried with "onLayout" but the "x" value is the same for each item.

Comment: show code or we can't help u

Answer (score 0):

You can use the https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressevent argument that gets passed into the child of `FlatList` in `TouchableHighlight`.

On this page https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist there is an example to dissect.

```
<FlatList
  ItemSeparatorComponent={
    Platform.OS !== 'android' &&
    (({highlighted}) => (
      <View
        style={[style.separator, highlighted && {marginLeft: 0}]}
      />
    ))
  }
  data={[{title: 'Title Text', key: 'item1'}]}
  renderItem={({item, index, separators}) => (
    <TouchableHighlight
      key={item.key}
      onPress={() => this._onPress(item)}
      onShowUnderlay={separators.highlight}
      onHideUnderlay={separators.unhighlight}>
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  )}
/>
```

`TouchableHighlight` inherits onPress from `TouchableWithoutFeedback` https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback

The onpress takes an item argument with location information you can use

Comment: Thank you Drew but in this way I will get the "press" coordinates. I would to know the item coordinates (with height and width of element included)

Comment: When you say "item" are you referring to the list item you clicked? If that's the case you can probably get the parent information from the item object. This will give you the target id of the parent node (aka the item) and then you can lookup that item at that moment to get its info https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressevent#target.

Comment: Thanks Drew. Yes, I mean the FlatList item. Have you an example for get x, y, width and height of target?